# Set Laravel storage permission to 777?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, chmod

For some reason, I had to set my laravel storage folder to 777.

I run this command `sudo chmod -R 775 storage/` and my permission error not resolved so then I changed the permission from 775 to 777 by running this command `sudo chmod -R 777 storage/`

My question is that 777 permission can cause any problem (Forbidden access || Security) in my laravel or its ok?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the best solution that I found.

Step 1: chown the root directory:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/root
```

Step 2: Grant FTP for uploading and working with files (for using any FTP client):

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu
```

Step 3: Set file permission to 644:

```
sudo find /path/to/root -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Step 4: Set directory permission to 755:

```
sudo find /path/to/root -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Step 5: Give rights for web server to read and write storage and cache

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Source: https://vijayasankarn.wordpress.com/2017/02/04/securely-setting-file-permissions-for-laravel-framework/

Comment: Thank you for your response but I really want to know by changing chmod to 777 any access or security threats might happen to my project or not?

Comment: @pejmankheyri As you can read from blog, it is a serious security concern.

Answer (score 6):

From the project's root run the following commands:

```
    sudo chmod -R gu+w storage/
    sudo chmod -R guo+w storage/
    sudo chmod -R gu+w bootstrap/cache/
    sudo chmod -R guo+w bootstrap/cache/
```

Comment: Could you explain what this does?

Comment: g: group, u: user, o: others, +w: add write permissions. Actually 1st and 3rd command are useless

Answer (score 0):

In short based on OP question is:
Set permission to: 775
And make sure that active users added to the group (check with `ls -alh` command)